# How to properly override jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am overriding the jquery ui method for close. In this way, I can have it close based on a `selected` variable I establish.

```
var originalCloseMethod = $input.data("autocomplete").close();
$input.data("autocomplete").close = function(event) {
  if (!selected){
    originalCloseMethod.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  selected = false;
};
```

It works great *except* for when it needs to make a regular closer. For example, if I click outside of the autocomplete div. The API then calls for close and returns this :

> originalCloseMethod is undefined

Which makes me realize that it's calling this method internally inside the UI.

This is why I am assuming that the best way to write this code, is to extend the UI not just override it.

My question is, how would I apply this same method as an extension as opposed to an override?

Comment: Didn't you want it to be: `var originalCloseMethod = $input.data("autocomplete").close;`

Comment: ? That's what I have isn't it ?

Comment: No. You call the `close` function and save it's return value, not saving a reference to it...

Comment: omfg, you're completely right. that is a genius remark. you are a genius.

Comment: So I added it as an answer... =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call the close function and save it's return value, not saving a reference to it:

```
var originalCloseMethod = $input.data("autocomplete").close();
```

Change it to:

```
var originalCloseMethod = $input.data("autocomplete").close;
```